# look for a unknown text file in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch script which checks if a text file exists in a directory or not. I am using the following command

```
if exist "test\dir\*.txt" 
(
    echo txt file exist
)
```

As if command does not differentiate upper and lower case at search, so I am planning to use find command but I am not able to use it with `*.txt`.

Can anybody please advise me how can I use find command to search a unknown text file?

Comment: Your code should have the `(` at the end of line one, after a space.

Answer (score 1):

To test for file existence, you can use any of the following

```
if exist "test\dir\*.txt" (
    echo File exists
) else (
    echo File does not exist
)


if exist "test\dir\*.txt" echo File exists


dir /a-d "test\dir\*.txt" > nul 2>nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo File does not exist
) else echo File exists


dir /a-d "test\dir\*.txt" >nul 2>nul && echo File Exists || echo File does not exist
```

Just to enumerate the habitual ways.

But, as you said, all of this constructs do not differentiate from upper or lower case.

`find` is used to locate text inside a file, not for file search. But, if the search must differentiate upper and lower case, the simple check for file existence in the previous samples must be converted into an enumeration of the files and then search into the list for the required files.

```
dir /a-d /b "test\dir\*.txt" 2>nul | find ".txt" > nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo File does not exist
) else echo File exists
```

But this will return the file exists for `myfile.txt.exe`. For things like this, `findstr` is more flexible, allowing to indicate where to search for the string. In this case, at the end of the line

```
dir /a-d /b "test\dir\*.txt" 2>nul | findstr /l /e /c:".txt" > nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo File does not exist
) else echo File exists
```

This enumerates the files matching the `*.txt`, and filter the list for those with the literal (the `/l` switch) `.txt` (the `/c:` parameter) in lower case (default behaviour), at the end of the line (`/e` switch)

Answer (score 0):

dir /s will search for a file pattern in a given directory and its sub-directories. Checking the ERRORLEVEL after execution will allow to know if the file was found or not.

Comment: Sorry i could not understand your description can you please give an example